# Get contents of php created div with variable id with JQuery

Tags: jquery

On my page I have a search form which generates a table for the results. In that table, each cells content is surrounded by a span tag with an ID based on the cells name and rows ID in the database. In addition the span gets a fixed class. Heres a printed example:

```
<td><span id="firstname_203" class="text">John</span></td>
```

What I am trying to do, is that when I hover the cell that contains the firstname, I want the firstname to appear on a different part of the page. I have tried the code below, but it only returns firstname=null:

```
( function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
    $(".text").hover(function() 
    {
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    var firstname=$("#firstname_"+ID).html();
    $($(".firstname")).html("firstname="+firstname);
    });
});
} ) ( jQuery );
```

It's the ID part that doesn't work because if i hardcode the ID (e.g. "#firstname_203") it works just fine.

When I think about it, the only thing I need to know is how to get the php generated integer following the ID.

Update:

When adding more variables (this).text didn't work as it returned the whole rows values. Instead I had to use this:

```
$("#table td:nth-child(1)").hover(function(event){
```

and return the cells as:

```
var firstname= $td.eq(0).text();
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just skip the whole Id kerfuffle and go straight to the `.html()`.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".text").hover(function() {
            var firstname = $(this).html();
            $(".firstname").html("firstname=" + firstname);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Also, you could probably just get away with using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

EDIT:

Given this html

```
<div class="userDetails">
    <span class="fname">Barry</span>
    <span class="lname">Smith</span>
</div>

<div class="firstname">Firstname</div>
<div class="lastname">Lastname</div>
```

You could do:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".userDetails").hover(function() {
            var firstName = $('.fname', this).text();
            var lastName = $('.lname', this).text();
            $(".firstname").html("firstname=" + firstName);
            $(".lastname").html("lastname=" + lastName);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I've created a jsFiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/HZRSW/

Comment: Yeah that worked aswell. But one problem occured when I tried to add more variables. When i added lastname (which is set to print out in .lastname) it prints both firstname and lastname in both places. I changed the ".text" to ".tr" which is the class of each row so I would get the entire contents of the row, but when i did, instead of printing first and last name in their respective divs (.firstname and .lastname) it prints both variables in both divs.

Comment: Updated question with more details.

Comment: That would work, but the span id's aren't static, they're like: fname_1 lname_1, fname_2 lname_2 and so on.

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery attribute selectors. You could do something like `var firstName = $('span[id^="fname"]', this).text();`. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/